# htaccess for laravel without affecting subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get htaccess working for laravel 5.4, but without it affecting the sub-domains that are created.

My current htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

What I've tried is setting an htaccess in the sub-domain folders with the follwing:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

As I read elsewhere this should stop the top domain htaccess, yet when for example I have a sub-domain like dev.example.com, it will redirect to dev.example.com/dev

Anyway of getting rid of the /dev at the end?

Folder structure:

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
public
storage
resources
routes
dev --> subdomain
```

Answer (score 0):

Upfront, I don't see how this `/dev` is related to the directives, you have shown. None of them do anything to add a `/dev` anywhere. Maybe it's just the subdirectory applied somehow.

---

The claim "this should stop the top domain htaccess" is not entirely true. From [Apache - How directives are applied](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#how)

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof.
>
> However, it is important to also remember that there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up. Directives are applied in the order that they are found.
>
> Therefore, a .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those, in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the main server configuration file itself.

So an .htaccess doesn't stop another .htaccess, but a directive overrides a directive. This means, you may have some directive from one .htaccess and another unrelated directive from the top level .htaccess.

---

In your case, `RewriteEngine on` just overrides `RewriteEngine on` from the main .htaccess file.

If you want to prevent any `RewriteRule` from the top .htaccess, I would rather try

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: I have just tried to turn RewriteEngine Off, this sadly seemed to have resulted in the same error. I also am aware of the current htaccess not showing why a subdomain it adding itself at the end, but my subdomains work perfectly without having the htaccess, just my top domain isn't

Comment: Unless there are any additional directives somewhere, I cannot see how the subdirectory is appended. The only way to see, is to look into Apache's log files.

Comment: I will look into the apache log files tonight, next to that, i may think the /dev is being added because it being a sub-domain since it's the folders name? I just updated the question showing the folder structure.

Comment: How is this subdomain configured? Is it a separate virtual host with `dev` as the document root?

Comment: It is indeed it's own virtualhost which sets dev as the document root, matter of fact, it's made with directadmin